# How to decrypt the first message sent from Mifare Desfire EV1

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes, mifare

Does anyone have a clue how to decrypt the first message sent from the card? I mean after the authentication success and then you send a command (for example 0x51 (GetRealTagUID). It returns 00+random32bits (always different). I try to decrypt it with:

```
        private byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted, byte[] iv)
            throws Exception {
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        return decrypted;
    }
```

And calling it with decrypt(sessionKey, response, iv)

IV = all zeros (16 bytes)

response = that 32randombits after the 0x51 command (just removed the two zeros)

Someone told me, that the IV changes after the first sent command (0x51). How to generate the right IV for decrypting that response? I think the all zeros is wrong, because the decrypted message is always different and it should be always same with the same card.

-EDIT-

After applying your (Michael Roland) instructions, the decrypted response is still just random bits. Here is my code (I think I'm doing something wrong):

```
            byte[] x = encrypt(sessionKey, iv, iv);

            byte[] rx = rotateBitsLeft(x);

            if ((rx[15] & 0x01) == 0x01)
                rx[15] = (byte) (rx[15] ^ 0x87);

            if ((rx[15] & 0x01) == 0x00)
                rx[15] = (byte) (rx[15] ^ 0x01);

            byte[] crc_k1 = rx;

            byte[] rrx = rotateBitsLeft(rx);

            if ((rrx[15] & 0x01) == 0x01)
                rrx[15] = (byte) (rrx[15] ^ 0x87);

            if ((rrx[15] & 0x01) == 0x00)
                rrx[15] = (byte) (rrx[15] ^ 0x01);

            byte[] crc_k2 = rrx;

            byte[] command = { (byte) 0x51, (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x00,
                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                    (byte) 0x00 };

            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
                command[i] = (byte) (command[i] ^ crc_k2[i]);
            }

            byte[] iv2 = encrypt(sessionKey, command, iv);

            byte[] RealUID = decrypt(sessionKey, ReadDataParsed, iv2);

            Log.e("RealUID", ByteArrayToHexString(RealUID));
```

-EDIT3-

Still returning always different values. I think the problem might lie here:

```
byte[] iv2 = encrypt(sessionKey, command, iv);
```

What IV to use when creating the new IV for decrypting the response? It is all zeros there.

Comment: hi! where you able to make this work?

Comment: Yeah :) I remember the 2 weeks horror when trying to solve this.

Comment: i feel you! great post it was a life saver! thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After authentication, the IV is reset to all-zeros. As you use AES authentication, you then have to calculate the CMAC for every follow-up command (even if CMAC is not actually appended to the command). So the CMAC calculation for your command will lead to correct IV initialization for decoding the response. I.e. the CMAC for the command is equal to the IV for decrypting the response. Similarly, for all further commands, the IV is the last cipher block from the previous encryption/CMAC.

---

**UPDATE:**

**How to calculate CMAC pad XOR value**

- Encrypt one block of zeros (`0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00`) with session key (using IV of zeros). -> `x[0..15]`
- Rotate `x[0..15]` one bit to the left. -> `rx[0..15]`
- If the last bit (bit 0 in `rx[15]`) is one: xor `rx[15]` with `0x86`.
- Store `rx[0..15]` as `crc_k1[0..15]`.
- Rotate `rx[0..15]` one bit to the left. -> `rrx[0..15]`
- If the last bit (bit 0 in `rrx[15]`) is one: xor `rrx[15]` with `0x86`.
- Store `rrx[0..15]` as `crc_k2[0..15]`.

**How to calculate CMAC**

- You pad the command using `0x80 0x00 0x00 ...` to the block size of the cipher (16 bytes for AES). If the command length matches a multiple of the block size, no padding is added.
- For your command (`0x51`) this would look like: `0x51 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00`
- If padding was added, xor the last 16 bytes of the padded command with `crc_k2[0..15]`.
- If no padding was added, xor the last 16 bytes of the command with `crc_k1[0..15]`.
- Encrypt (in send mode, i.e. `enc(IV xor datablock)`, cipher text of previous block is new IV) the result with the session key.
- The ciphertext of the last block is the CMAC and the new IV.

---

**UPDATE 2:**

**How to rotate a bit vector to the left for one bit**

```
public void rotateLeft(byte[] data) {
    byte t = (byte)((data[0] >>> 7) & 0x001);
    for (int i = 0; i < (data.length - 1); ++i) {
        data[i] = (byte)(((data[i] << 1) & 0x0FE) | ((data[i + 1] >>> 7) & 0x001));
    }
    data[data.length - 1] = (byte)(((data[data.length - 1] << 1) & 0x0FE) | t);
}
```

Comment: How to calculate it? I have searched all over the internet. Can you give me example function how to calculate it? Like how to calculate it right after the authentication and after the first command.

Comment: where you check (r)rx[15] you should check only for bit 0 = 1 or 0 and not for the whole byte

Comment: `rrx[15] & 0x01 == 0x01`

Comment: I dont understand :( So how do I replace this:       if (rx[15] == 0x01)
rx[15] = (byte) (rx[15] ^ 0x87);
if (rx[15] == 0x00)
rx[15] = (byte) (rx[15] ^ 0x01);

Comment: I think its my LeftShift function! All else seems to be working. How that bit shifting works in Java? How to shift those bits to the left?

Comment: Thx man! But it still not working :( Is there any other errors in the code?

Comment: `if ((rx[15] & 0x00) == 0x00)` should be `if ((rx[15] & 0x01) == 0x00)` (same for `rrx` of course...)

Comment: I LOVE YOU MAN! It is finally working! But there is still some very minor bug. It isn't returning the right value always. Only sometimes.

Comment: @Stonde wrote: I did some tests and it seems like it returns the right value if all those if clauses (rx and rrx) succeed. Otherwise it decrypts wrong. What can be the solution?

Comment: Make sure to use if-else statements forr checking the lower bit of byte 15 in `(r)rx`, otherwise you will trigger both cases if that bit is 1 in the first place. This will lead to an invalid result. I.e. use `if ((rx[15] & 0x01) == 0x01) rx[15] = (byte) (rx[15] ^ 0x87); else rx[15] = (byte) (rx[15] ^ 0x01);` (same for `rrx`).

Comment: Btw. this discussion runs into general Java programming knowledge/understanding and becomes slightly off-topic with regard to the initial question!

Comment: Then it never returns right value :( It returned sometimes if I had those all if's and it went to all those if clauses. Only then it returned right value. Maybe there is no need for CRC checking? How to modify the code then?

Comment: Sorry, forget the last part, I just found my mistake: Use `if ((rx[15] & 0x01) == 0x01) rx[15] = (byte) (rx[15] ^ 0x86);` (same for `rrx`) no else branch, no test for `== 0x00`, no xor with `0x01`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: i am writting a programm to genreate cmac, my iv, and key and data is as the below:
    var iv = this.StringToByteArray("b987074d3f60eef6c18034551aa79e09");
    var sissionkey = this.StringToByteArray("227eac508fb2d130e0451988d51f8dd0");
    var commandRead = new byte[] { 0xbd, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0f, 0x00, 0x00};
can you generate cmac by my data, and then i compare your result with myself

Answer (score 1):

It's not c/c++ section but enter my position, I'm looking at a possible bug from the C developer.
I can't proof Java implementation here. But i think @Michael Roland way is not true! Maby! Maby i'm wrong!

Sry for my English,- its terrible :) but it's not my native language. I'm Russian.

Check first MSB (7 - bit) of array[0] and then shiffting this to the left. And then XOR if MSB 7 bit was == 1;
Or save first MSB bit of array[0] and after shiffting put this bit at the end of array[15] at the end (LSB bit).

Just proof it's here:
https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN10922.pdf

Try this way:

> Zeros <- 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>
> SessionKey <- 00 01 02 03 E3 27 64 0C 0C 0D 0E 0F 5C 5D B9 D5
>
> Data <- 6F 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

First u have to encrypt 16 bytes (zeros) with SesionKey;

```
enc_aes_128_ecb(Zeros);
```

And u get EncryptedData.

> EncryptedData <- 3D 08 A2 49 D9 71 58 EA 75 73 18 F2 FA 6A 27 AC

Check bit 7 [MSB - LSB] of EncryptedData[0] == 1? switch i to true;

```
 bool i = false;
  if (EncryptedData[0] & 0x80){
    i = true;
  }
```

Then do Shiffting of all EncryptedData to 1 bit <<.

```
ShiftLeft(EncryptedData,16);
```

And now, when i == true - XOR the last byte [15] with 0x87

```
if (i){
    ShiftedEncryptedData[15] ^= 0x87;
  }
```

> 7A 11 44 93 B2 E2 B1 D4 EA E6 31 E5 F4 D4 4F 58

Save it as KEY_1.

Try bit 7 [MSB - LSB] of ShiftedEncryptedData[0] == 1?

```
 i = false;
  if (ShiftedEncryptedData[0] & 0x80){
    i = true;
  }
```

Then do Shiffting of all ShiftedEncryptedData to 1 bit <<.

```
ShiftLeft(ShiftedEncryptedData,16);
```

And now, when i == true - XOR the last byte [15] with 0x87

```
if (i){
   ShiftedEncryptedData[15] ^= 0x87;
}
```

> F4 22 89 27 65 C5 63 A9 D5 CC 63 CB E9 A8 9E B0

Save it as KEY_2.

Now we take our Data (6F **80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00**)

As Michael say's - pad command with 0x80 0x00...

XOR Data with KEY_2 - if command was padded, or KEY_1 if don't.
If we have more like 16 bytes (32 for example) u have to XOR just last 16 bytes.

Then encrypt it:

```
enc_aes_128_ecb(Data);
```

Now u have a CMAC.

> CD C0 52 62 6D F6 60 CA 9B C1 09 FF EF 64 1A E3

---

> Zeros <- 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>
> SessionKey <- 00 01 02 03 E3 27 64 0C 0C 0D 0E 0F 5C 5D B9 D5
>
> Key_1 <- 7A 11 44 93 B2 E2 B1 D4 EA E6 31 E5 F4 D4 4F 58
>
> Key_2 <- F4 22 89 27 65 C5 63 A9 D5 CC 63 CB E9 A8 9E B0
>
> Data <- 6F 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>
> CMAC <- CD C0 52 62 6D F6 60 CA 9B C1 09 FF EF 64 1A E3

C/C++ function:

```
void ShiftLeft(byte *data, byte dataLen){
  for (int n = 0; n < dataLen - 1; n++) {
   data[n] = ((data[n] << 1) | ((data[n+1] >> 7)&0x01));
  }
  data[dataLen - 1] <<= 1;
}
```

Have a nice day :)