# Decrypt DESFire ReadData Session

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, mifare, desfire

We´re struggeling with the decryption of DESFire Data. We´ve authenticated successfully and could decrypt RndA´ which was the same as the RndA we´ve created.

Now we try to read an encyphered File from position 0 for 16 bytes.

From some java library we could figure out, that we have to use the encyphered Command as IV for the decryption. Is that right?

Here the examples:

```
SessionKey: 0ba1caf83a26a72170149b7504895f34
ReadCommand: bd00000000100000
Crc32C for Cmd: D9CEE76B
Secret: 6a0d0f0d5c8f054b1e5914a42e49728622774c6272e5c34a69ed302251576aaf
```

So now we concat the ReadCommand with Crc32C:

```
bd00000000100000D9CEE76B
```

Then we padd Zeros up to 16 Bytes

```
bd00000000100000D9CEE76B00000000
```

Then we generate e(cmd + crc + padding) with session key and IV 0 to gain the next iv for decrypting the resposne:

```
77E24803B5401C61F657607923E5A318
```

Now we decrypt the secret with session Key and IV:=e(cmd + crc32) and are getting:

```
D1E9A4726C2A5C3FD5938E714C07524EF1F74BD9000000000000000000000000
```

There are many Zeros which let me think we are not far away from the answer.
So please someone tell us, what is wrong?

We are using this library for [Crc32C](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Crc32C.NET/)
And here the full code we are using within a test:

```
        [Theory]
    [InlineData("6a0d0f0d5c8f054b1e5914a42e49728622774c6272e5c34a69ed302251576aaf", "0ba1caf83a26a72170149b7504895f34", "bd00000000100000")]
    public void DecryptData_Test(string secretS, string sessionKeyS, string cmdS) 
    {
        var cryptoAlgoFactory = new Func<SymmetricAlgorithm>(() => Aes.Create());
        var keyLength = 16;

        var secret = EncriptionHelper.StringToByte(secretS);
        var sessionKey = EncriptionHelper.StringToByte(sessionKeyS);
        var cmd = EncriptionHelper.StringToByte(cmdS);

        var crytoAlgo = cryptoAlgoFactory();
        crytoAlgo.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        crytoAlgo.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

        var encryptor = crytoAlgo.CreateEncryptor(sessionKey, new byte[keyLength]);

        var crc32 = BitConverter.GetBytes(Crc32C.Crc32CAlgorithm.Compute(cmd));

        var padding = 0;
        if ((cmd.Length + crc32.Length) % keyLength != 0)
            padding = keyLength - ((cmd.Length + crc32.Length) % keyLength);

        var result = new byte[cmd.Length + crc32.Length + padding];

        Array.Copy(cmd, result, cmd.Length);
        Array.Copy(crc32, 0, result, cmd.Length, crc32.Length);

        var iv = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(result, 0, result.Length);

        crytoAlgo = cryptoAlgoFactory();
        crytoAlgo.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        crytoAlgo.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

        var decryptor = crytoAlgo.CreateDecryptor(sessionKey, iv);

        var plain = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(secret, 0, secret.Length);

        Assert.NotNull(plain);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We´ve found out, that we have to encrypt the command with CMACing and without CRC32C.

Therefore the following solution:

```
SessionKey: 0ba1caf83a26a72170149b7504895f34
ReadCommand: bd00000000100000
Secret: 6a0d0f0d5c8f054b1e5914a42e49728622774c6272e5c34a69ed302251576aaf
```

First Encrypt the cmd with [CMACing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503060/how-to-decrypt-the-first-message-sent-from-mifare-desfire-ev1/20504667#20504667) to get the following IV for further decrypting (Note to use the SessionKey):

```
A70BEC41E95A706F11F7DA3D59F2F256
```

Then decrypt the secret in CBC Mode with IV cmac(cmd) to get the result:

```
01000030303030313233343536100300F1F74BD9000000000000000000000000
```

Within the CMACing there is still something wrong so we used an [NuGet Packege](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle/) which worked fine.